# magento diplays 2 different modules with different namespaces in same page

Tags: php, magento, namespaces, router

I have created two differents modules Test and First associated to different namespaces : Pfay (Test), Train (First).

For some reason this link `http://localhost/magento/index.php/first/index/` will call the function IndexAction of Test/controllers/indexController.php as well

Here are the codes :
for Test

```
<?php
 class Pfay_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
 public function indexAction()
 {
      $this->loadLayout();
      $this->renderLayout();
 }
}
?>
```

for First:

```
    <?php
    class Train_First_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
         public function indexAction()
         {
              $this->loadLayout();
              $this->renderLayout();
              // echo "First Index";
         }
    }

    ?>
```

config.xml (test)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Pfay_Test>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Pfay_Test>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                 <frontName>test</frontName>
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
       <layout>
               <updates>
                    <test>
                         <file>test.xml</file>
                     </test>
                </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
     <blocks>
         <test>
              <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
         </test>
      </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

config.xml (first)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Train_First>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Train_First>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Train_First</module>
                 <frontName>first</frontName>
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
       <layout>
           <updates>
                <first>
                     <file>first.xml</file>
                 </first>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
     <blocks>
         <first>
              <class>Train_First_Block</class>
         </first>
      </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

test.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>
          <reference name="content">
          </reference>
      </default>
      <routeurfrontend_index_index>
           <reference name="content">
                <block type="test/monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc"
                          template="test/afficher.phtml" />
           </reference>
      </routeurfrontend_index_index>
      <routeurfrontend_index_mamethode>
           <reference name="content">
                <block type="test/monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc"
                          template="test/afficher2.phtml" />
           </reference>
      </routeurfrontend_index_mamethode>
</layout>
```

first.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>
          <reference name="content">
          </reference>
      </default>
      <routeurfrontend_index_index>
           <reference name="content">
                <block type="first/firstblock"  name="firstblocindex"
                          template="first/first_afficher.phtml" />
           </reference>
      </routeurfrontend_index_index>
      <routeurfrontend_index_mamethode>
           <reference name="content">
                <block type="first/firstblock"  name="firstblocmamethode"
                          template="first/first_afficher.phtml" />
           </reference>
      </routeurfrontend_index_mamethode>
</layout>
```

And for some reason `http://localhost/magento/index.php/test/index/` does not work anymore (404 not found).  There are probably some conflicts but I can't find where.

You can see here the problems.

[image]

Comment: Is  // echo "First Index";  giving you any result when uncommented ?

Comment: yes it will write "First Index" at the top of the page first/index. The fact is that contents that should be in test/index is in first/index as well, but the page (first/index ) does work.

Comment: I have updated with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config file you have created a router alias,

```
<routeurfrontend>
```

which is common for both the plugins, you will need to rename one of them, and correspondingly make changes in the appropriate layout xml. This should work.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked. I thought routeurfrontend was common. But now that I think about this, routeur is french ^^